# Get newest azure blob storage files to Logic Apps Send Email flow

Tags: azure, email, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

How can I get the newest file to be attached to the Logic Apps Send Email (Outlook) email body? For example, there was a workflow on my Azure Function that stores the file into Azure blob storage the file will append based on date information on the name of the file, and then this Send Email will attach the file into the body email.

Comment: as you mentioned in the above that every time   does your function will create a new blob or it will append the existing blob ?

Comment: Hi @VenkateshDodda-MT , my file will append because the file contains the date information.

Comment: so every time when the logic got trigger , the function will create a new file with the data as name of the file is it correct ?

Comment: Yeah, that's right @VenkateshDodda-MT , for example: `file_20211230.csv`, `file_20211231.csv`, then it will attach the newest `file_20211231.csv`. Is it possible?

Comment: lets continue the discussion over this chat room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240558/70527993-get-newest-azure-blob-storage-files-to-logic-apps-send-email-flow

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the above shared requirement, we have created a sample workflow in our local environment.

In our workflow we have hardcoded the `blobname` using the compose action, post that we are checking whether that particular blob is present in the storage account or not.

If the blob is present in the storage account it will pull the content of the blob & it will trigger an email(used `Send an email action` to sent email) by appending the content of that blob as an attachment to that email.

**Here is the logic app screenshot:**

[image]

[image]

**Here is the output screenshot:**

[image]

**Note:**
In our workflow, we have hardcoded the name of the blob. In your case, you need  fetch the `blobname` from the function app  output.

Comment: This is a very clear answer, thanks!